# Проектирование визуализатора на основе паттерна MVC

Tags: mvc, actionscript, шаблоны-проектирования, uml

Необходимо реализовать что-то типа визуализатора.
Приложение должно реализовываться на основе паттерна MVC (задан набор интерфейсов для модели, представления и контроллера - соответственно мое приложение должно их реализовывать).
Я не знаю, как спроектировать логику приложения, то есть построить те же UML диаграммы! Посоветуйте с чего начать? Что почитать?

Comment: Конечное приложение - это визуализатор **чего?**

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать - алгоритма, в общем и целом усложненный поиск в глубину.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Начинать с `UML` диаграмм, не имея опыта проектирования ПО - это, простите, самоубийство.*

Задача на визуализацию алгоритма - классический и хороший способ понять `MVC`. Конкретно для вашего случая разбиение `Model - View - Controller` представляется достаточно очевидным способом:

- Есть **модель данных** - это вход вашего алгоритма. Поскольку большинство алгоритмов можно отождествлять с конечными автоматами, то данные в любой момент алгоритма определяются единственным образом. *Модель работает с некоторым функциональным объектом `Step`, который совершает один шаг алгоритма (соответствующим образом меняя модель).*
- Есть одно или несколько возможных **представлений** модели данных. В зависимости от применяемого языка программирования, этот класс чаще всего расширяет / использует какие-либо системные классы для отображения *(в вашем случае удобно экстендить `MovieClip`)*
- Есть **контроллер**, который проецирует действия в модель. В тривиальнешем случае это будет одно-единственное действие - ***сделать шаг алгоритма** с помощью объекта-мутатора `Step`.

---

После того, как вы в вашем приложении сможете реализовать описанные выше задачи, расширяйте функционал.

Предусмотрите возможность самому задавать свойства модели, свойства алгоритма *(т.е свойства `Step`)*, возможность делать шаги назад, разные виды для модели и т.п. **На этом этапе можете уже сгенерировать готовую `UML` диаграмму по вашему проекту** и подумать, что можно сделать лучше.

Настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться хотя бы с основами библиотеки [**PureMVC**](http://puremvc.org/) - `Mediator`, `Observer`, `Proxy` и т.п, поскольку знание и умение их применять сильно облегчает программирование с помощью `MVC`.

Comment: не где не вижу про язык, но если это на асп.нэт, то там уже есть готовый фреймворк

Comment: @Gorets Это конечно очень важное замечание, однако в тегах вопроса указан `ActionScript`. Да и тем более, у `PureMVC` есть порты под все популярные языки.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы начинал так, если для себя, то

1. сел с карандашом и бумагой и нарисовал главные классы, их методы
2. нарисовал бы схему БД и ее таблици с колонками

Если, не для себя, все тоже, только в конце перенес все в удобный для других вид ( в те же UML)

Потом, посмотрел на то что я уже знаю, и то чего еще не понимаю, например, разобрался с MVC. Ну а дальше, с непонятными моментами - опять на форум =)